# Editing a tag in XpathDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathdocument

I have XpathDocument object which has content like

```
<MainTag>
   <XYZTag>
      <Tag>
       <CTag ID="ABS"/>
      </Tag>
     </XYZTag>
     <ABCTag>
       <CTag ID="ABS"/>
      </ABCTag>
      <FGHTag>
       <CTag ID="ABS"/>
      </FGHTag>
</MainTag>
```

I want to remove

```
<Tag> </Tag>
```

to make it look like

```
<MainTag>
   <XYZTag>

       <CTag ID="ABS"/>

     </XYZTag>
     <ABCTag>
       <CTag ID="ABS"/>
      </ABCTag>
      <FGHTag>
       <CTag ID="ABS"/>
      </FGHTag>
</MainTag>
```

I tried assign innerXML to outerXML, apparently not allowed. Myriad of online solution also not work. Is it possible to have this change in XPathDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be XPathDocument. You can do this easily using [XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.7.2). Here's one example.

```
var xml = @"
<MainTag>
      <Tag>
       <CTag ID='ABS'/>
      </Tag>
</MainTag>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var tagNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Tag");

var ctagNode = tagNode.FirstChild;
tagNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(ctagNode, tagNode);
```